# How to stop negative number with react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have used React Hook for increment and decrement numbers. But I have faced a problem when decrease below 0 then count minus value, I don't want minus value,
How can I stop minus value with react hook ?

I have tried this code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Home = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const onClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };
  const onClickDec = () => {
    setCount(count - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Please click me for increase {count}</h1>
      <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick={onClick}>
        +
      </button>
      <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick={onClickDec}>
        -
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Any suggestion, please.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever `count` is decreased get the maximum value (using `Math.max()`) of `count - 1` after and 0:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Home = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const onClick = () => {
    setCount(c => c + 1);
  };
  const onClickDec = () => {
    setCount(c => Math.max(c - 1, 0));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Please click me for increase {count}</h1>
      <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick={onClick}>
        +
      </button>
      <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick={onClickDec}>
        -
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Home />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

You can use the same idea if you want to limit increase to a certain number using `Math.min()`:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Home = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const onClick = () => {
    setCount(c => Math.min(c + 1, 3));
  };
  const onClickDec = () => {
    setCount(c => Math.max(c - 1, 0));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Please click me for increase {count}</h1>
      <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick={onClick}>
        +
      </button>
      <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick={onClickDec}>
        -
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Home />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Imo. the simplest solution would be to disable the button.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Home = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const onClick = () => {
setCount(count + 1);
  };
  const onClickDec = () => {
setCount(count - 1);
  };

  return (
<div>
  <h1>Please click me for increase {count}</h1>
  <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick={onClick}>
    +
  </button>
  <button disabled={count < 1} className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick={onClickDec}>
    -
  </button>
</div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Home />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: wow! it's also interesting when the value is 0 then minus is disabled. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful. Avoids negative values by conditionally hiding the (-) button. Also gives a RESET button.

```
class ClassCount extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    
      this.state = {
         count:0
      }
    }

    handleIncrement=()=>{
        this.setState(prevState =>{
          return{count: prevState.count + 1}
        })
    }
    handleDecrement=()=>{
        this.setState((prevState)=>{
            return{count: prevState.count - 1}
        })
    }
    handleReset=()=>{
        this.setState((prevState)=>{
            return{count: 0}
        })
    }

  render() {
      var mycount = this.state.count;
    return (
      <div>
          <h3>Count is {mycount}</h3>
          <button className='btn btn-success m-1' onClick={this.handleIncrement}>+</button>
          {
              mycount >=1 ? <button className='btn btn-danger m-1' onClick={this.handleDecrement}>-</button> : ''
          }
          {
              mycount >0 ? <button className='btn btn-info m-2' onClick={this.handleReset}>RESET</button> : ''
          }
          
          
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to change your onClickDec function. As like

```
const onClickDec = (e) => {
   setCount(count - 1);

   if(count <= 0 ) {
      setCount(0);
      e.target.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")
   } else {
      e.target.removeAttribute("disabled");
   }
}
```