# how can i stop the count at 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio, tailwind-css

I am using use state want to stop count at 0 it goes in -1,-2,-3etc on click (add to cart button)

```
 <div className="border-2 rounded-lg leading-[23.8px]">
              <div className="flex items-start justify-center gap-2 ">
                <button onClick={() => setCount(count-1)} className="flex self-center p-2 text-[red] hover:bg-[red] hover:text-white rounded active:bg-red-700">
                  <IoIosRemove />
                </button>
                <div className="flex self-center">
                  <p>{count}</p>
                </div>

                <button  onClick={() => setCount(count +1)}  className="flex self-center p-2 text-[red] hover:bg-[red] hover:text-white rounded active:bg-red-700">
                  <IoIosAdd />
                </button>
              </div>
          </div>
```

I expect any if statement or button disable property when decrement reaches 0

Comment: Instead of `setCount(count - 1)` use `setCount(count < 1 ? 0 : count - 1)`

Comment: This can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66077238/11095009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe separate out the logic into separate functions - the first to test the value of count, and updating the state as necessary depending on the `name` of the button, and the second to test that whether the state is less than/equal to zero which can be used to disable the button.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);

  // Destructure the name of the button, and
  // increment/decrement the count based on its
  // value. If the count is equal or greater than zero
  // update the state
  function handleClick(e) {
    const { name } = e.target;
    const newCount = name === 'increment'
      ? count + 1
      : count - 1;
    if (newCount >= 0) setCount(newCount);
  }

  // Return true is the state is less than
  // or equal to zero
  function isDisabled() {
    return count <= 0;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        name="decrement"
        onClick={handleClick}
        disabled={isDisabled()}
      >-
      </button>
      <span className="count">{count}</span>
      <button
        name="increment"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >+
      </button>
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
button { width: 25px; height: 25px;}
.count { margin: 0 0.5em; }
button:disabled { background-color: #ffcccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: disabled attribute worked thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
onClick={() => {
if (count > 0) setCount(count-1)
}}
```